# How to customize the line character length in elpy?

Tags: syntax, elpy, ide

I am using elpy for my Python development, but I would like to set the per-line character limit to 120 instead of the default 80 used by PEP8. Any suggestions on how I can do this? Even better, it would be great if I can customize this setting on a per-project basis.

I have tried the following:

- `M-x customize-group elpy`
- `M-x customize-mode elpy-mode`
- `M-x customize-mode python-mode`

but I can't seem to find the option that customizes the line character limit.

Comment: I suspect you want fill-column.

Comment: @Dan can you elaborate a bit? I tried setting fill-column (`M-x set-fill-column` and via `M-x customize-variable fill-column`), but elpy still shows an error for lines longer than 79 characters, with the message `E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)`. I tried refreshing the buffer too, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like something that needs to be set through the `flake8` config file or through the `autopep8` config file depending on what you want. Take a look at the configuration page https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to customize per project basis, you can create a `setup.cfg` with custom config like this

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 160
```

If you want to change this globally, you can change flake8 config as mentioned here https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#user-configuration

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I needed, and now I see that I can use the flake8 config for my elpy-mode. It makes sense, because I believe elpy uses flake8 as the default syntax checker under the hood.

Comment: That link is dead - this seems like the current version: [https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/configuration.html#user-configuration](https://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/configuration.html#user-configuration)

Comment: Would someone please tell me how this file is supposed to be created if it doesn't exist? And what's the path?

Comment: @Qohelet You can manually create the file and add the required sections to it. By default, it should be in your project root directory. https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html

Comment: @n1k31t4 Thanks for the new link. Update it.

Comment: @ChillarAnand - tried it and it doesn't work, that's how I came here. Emacs still complains

Comment: If you're on Linux/Mac, the config should be in `~/.config/flake8` (**not** `~/.config/.flake8`)